# Installed Ubuntu over Zorin OS and kept /home, but probably kept some bad configurations

Tags: 20.04, configuration, budgie

Recently I decided to install Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 LTS after running Zorin OS (based on Ubuntu 18.04). Zorin was installed on a separate root partition, and I had another partition for /home. Naturally, I installed Budgie over / and mounted the other partition as /home.

The main reason I decided to install Budgie is that I had a particular program (AnyLogic), built in Java, that gave me some weird freezing issues even for seemingly easy operations (i.e. putting a simple plot object from the palette to the canvas, or opening example projects). The idea was to try and refresh the system and thus see if that was the culprit behind the weird issues, as I might have introduced some issues inside my Zorin OS system by installing or configuring some things. My intuition turned out correct, since I installed a fresh Zorin OS on another computer (that also gave me issues with AnyLogic before the fresh install) and then tried Anylogic--which worked just fine, with no issues.

Everything went smoothly after Budgie install, and plenty of configuration was kept--which really was great, as I only had to install many programs and they continued working as if no new system was installed.

However, this also had the bad consequence that AnyLogic still kept its freezing and other problems. My guess is that there were some configuration files or something else kept in /home that remained, and now present problems with Budgie (as / was formatted during install but /home was kept and simply mounted as home).

I also tried to delete AnyLogic's .AnyLogicPLE folder, but to no avail--AnyLogic creates a new such folder, but the problem persists. I also tried deleting other such hidden (sub)folders in /home that mentioned anylogic in any way, but it didn't help.

**Now my question is, how can I go about really refreshing the system?** I am ready to even reinstall everything if needed be because I really need this program to be functional. But I'd rather not do that and go through the whole setup again.

Can I, instead, delete all such hidden folders in /home and expect no big issues i.e. when programs run they'd create them again? Or how can I determine which exact such folders are accessed by AnyLogic so that I can try removing them in particular?

What would you guys suggest in this situation?

Sorry for the long letter, but I thought details would be needed here. I am a novice at Linux, so please bear with me.

Comment: There are lots of configs that live under your home folder. If some of those are corrupted or misconfigured, you're dragging those problems from your last installation to your new one by keeping the same home folder. Since you want a clean start, you should probably back up your data and reinstall the OS, including the home folder.  Don't install "on top" of your old system, wipe/format before installation.

Comment: Note, even if you do a *clean* install, but the replace your $HOME (/home/$USER/) with a version from the prior OS, you may re-introduce the same problems anyway. I'd recommend either tracking down & fixing your issue, or I suppose clean install, but recovery of 'new' files in /home (ie. don't replace automatically unless you've assessed the consequences of them)... to me the speed of both is about the same (the second will be dictated by how much you've configured your system & what documentation you keep of your changes; it can be far faster)..   my 2c

Comment: I think it has something to do with broken GTK & its webkit (see, for example, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329699/how-to-solve-gtk-warning-messages-how-to-restore-ubuntu-system-files-without-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I 'solved' the problem by wiping everything and installing anew.

I still don't have an idea what was behind the exact problem, which is too bad since if it happens again in the future I'll have to delete everything again. But at least it is a solution of a kind.

Thanks to @Nmath and @guiverc for the suggestions.