# How to solve GTK warning messages / how to restore Ubuntu system files without reinstalling everything

Tags: nvidia, steam, gtk, budgie

I am asking this question as it seems that this problem poses significant issues for several programs that I'm using. Originally, this issue stemmed from me having to reinstall the whole Ubuntu Budgie system because some configurations were kept from the previous Zorin OS installation (as I simply remounted /home instead of wiping it clean), and I couldn't start a program: AnyLogic. That question is here: [Installed Ubuntu over Zorin OS and kept /home, but probably kept some bad configurations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329227/installed-ubuntu-over-zorin-os-and-kept-home-but-probably-kept-some-bad-config?noredirect=1#comment2265744_1329227)

The clean install solved the problem temporarily. What I noticed, though, is that AnyLogic asks to install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 if not present on the PC during install. Alright, fine, I give it permission, and then it works. AnyLogic worked for some days with no issues. Steam also worked with no issues.

However, I recently messed around with NVidia X Server, where I first put it in a NVidia On-Demand mode, ran Steam and some other games in Lutris, they ran on Intel graphics and didn't use the dedicated NVidia GPU, and then put it back on NVidia Performance Mode. After a reboot I tried running steam, but it didn't run. Tried reinstalling it from Ubuntu Software Store, and then from Steam website, but to no avail. Steam works during its starting phase when it checks for updates, but when it needs to start the UI crashes.

It seems that this somehow broke the GTK or webkit thing (whatever it is). Now both Steam and AnyLogic don't work anymore and they both give out Gtk warning messages.

So, for example, starting Steam in console poses the following error messages:

> Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6379350 Gtk-Message: 20:35:48.220: Failed to
> load module "appmenu-gtk-module" Gtk-Message: 20:35:48.220: Failed to
> load module "gail" Gtk-Message: 20:35:48.220: Failed to load module
> "atk-bridge"
>
> (steam:12737): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:35:48.224: Unable to locate theme
> engine in module_path: "adwaita",
>
> (steam:12737): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:35:48.225: Unable to locate theme
> engine in module_path: "adwaita",
> /usr/share/themes/Pocillo-dark-slim/gtk-2.0/main.rc:1090: error:
> unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
> /usr/share/themes/Pocillo-dark-slim/gtk-2.0/apps.rc:91: error:
> unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
>
> (steam:12737): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:35:48.226: Unable to locate theme
> engine in module_path: "adwaita", libGL error: No matching fbConfigs
> or visuals found libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast Steam: An
> X Error occurred X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext Major
> opcode of failed request:  152 Serial number of failed request:  54
> xerror_handler: X failed, continuing Steam: An X Error occurred X
> Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for
> operation) Major opcode of failed request:  152 Value in failed
> request:  0x0 Serial number of failed request:  53 xerror_handler: X
> failed, continuing Steam: An X Error occurred X Error of failed
> request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) Major opcode of
> failed request:  152 Serial number of failed request:  55
> xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
> assert_20210406203546_1.dmp[12806]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
> /tmp/dumps/assert_20210406203546_1.dmp
> /home/[user]/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 771: 12737 Segmentation
> fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH"
> "$@"

Starting AnyLogic works, but then it freezes on some actions, even some very simple ones. Two examples of error messages:

> (AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition:10941): Gtk-WARNING **:
> 20:29:17.639: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget
> with width -1 and height -1
>
> (AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition:10941): Gtk-WARNING **:
> 20:29:41.008: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2)
> while allocating gadget (node separator, owner GtkSeparatorToolItem)
>
> (AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition:10941): Gtk-WARNING **:
> 20:29:41.009: Negative content height -7 (allocation 1, extents 4x4)
> while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

and

> (AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition:9861): Gtk-WARNING **:
> 20:25:29.987: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget
> with width -1 and height -1
>
> (AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition:9861): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
> 20:25:33.081: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
> in GtkScrollbar
>
> (AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition:9861): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
> 20:25:33.082: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
> in GtkScrollbar
>
> (AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition:9861): Gtk-WARNING **:
> 20:25:54.331: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2)
> while allocating gadget (node separator, owner GtkSeparatorToolItem)
>
> (AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition:9861): Gtk-WARNING **:
> 20:25:54.332: Negative content height -7 (allocation 1, extents 4x4)
> while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

Weirdly enough, when trying to load a particular sample project in AnyLogic, if I have the program window at half-size, it loads. But then, when I try to enlarge the window it freezes. It seems that there's some GTK UI element that is not shown when half-size, but revealed and thus loaded when enlarging the window.

This all leads me to believe that it is a problem with that Gtk thingy. Something with the UI and windows of both Steam and AnyLogic.

**Now, my question is, how can I fix this? How can I restore the original libraries that came with Ubuntu Budgie, but not reinstall everything? Or maybe you have a better idea? Reinstall/restore GTK somehow??**

Thanks,
A

Comment: Time t to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ahh, but you see, I can't go and reinstall everything whenever a program decides to mess with some GTK libraries. It's simply too much work setting everything back again.